# Sort a multi-dimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i do not unstand the way to sort a multi-dimensional array in php. I have a structure like this:

```
Array (
   [0] (
      ['vname'] => "Bernt"
      ['nname'] => "Mayer"
      ['kl_name'] => "ZR4"
   )
   [1] (
      ['vname'] => "Albert"
      ['nname'] => "Mayer"
      ['kl_name'] => "TR4"
   )
)
```

My goal is now to first sort by kl_name, and then by nname and then vname. Most important is kl_name.
First i tought i should make objects and store them in the array, but i think sorting them is even more complex. php.net has a nice article about array_multisort, but year, i dont understand it :/

Comment: If you're getting those values from a database, you might as well sort it directly by modifying your query

Comment: Also extremely related if not a duplicate: [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to sort the array with a user defined function (with [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)).

You can then manually specify how you'd like the items to be ordered using the `kl_name`, `nname` and `vname` attributes.

Something like this:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['kl_name'] !== $b['kl_name']) {
        return strcmp($a['kl_name'], $b['kl_name']);
    } else if ($a['nname'] !== $b['nname']) {
        return strcmp($a['nname'], $b['nname']);
    } else {
        return strcmp($a['vname'], $b['vname']);
    }
});
```

The function will first attempt to sort by `kl_name`, then by `nname` and finally by `vname` if all previous values are equal.

Comment: Year! Thats works great in my case. never saw usort bevor (shame on me) but it looks great. Has someone an idea about performance of usort and array_multisort?

Comment: That's an interesting question. I'd suspect `array_multisort` to be quicker as the sorting takes place in PHP's C code rather than the userland callback function, but this speedup might be offset by the need to transpose rows/columns at the start. If you want to know then you'll have to measure it!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_multisort` for this.

```
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $kl_name[$key] = $row['kl_name'];
    $nname[$key]   = $row['nname'];
    $vname[$key]   = $row['vname'];
}

// Sort
array_multisort($kl_name, SORT_ASC, $nname, SORT_ASC, $vname, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

See http://php.net/array_multisort for more details.

Comment: If you have PHP >= 5.5, then [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) could be useful here instead of the `foreach`.  Example: https://eval.in/173777

Comment: I've never understood `array_multisort`.  So, you need to create an array for each field you want, then sort by all of them?

Comment: No, I don't really understand it either - I cribbed off the documentation to produce the answer. It sorts several arrays at once, making sure that swaps made on one array are made to all of them. The annoying first step is required to transpose the row-oriented dataset into a column-oriented form.

Answer (score 1):

I've never understood `array_multisort` either.  I just use `usort` for things like this.  What you do is, you compare the 1st field, and if it's the same, then you compare the 2nd... and so on.

So, it would look something like this (assuming `$data` is your array).

```
usort($data, function($a, $b){
    $sort_kl_name = strnatcasecmp($a['kl_name'], $b['kl_name']);
    if($sort_kl_name === 0){
        $sort_nname = strnatcasecmp($a['nname'], $b['nname']);
        if($sort_kl_name === 0){
            return strnatcasecmp($a['vname'], $b['vname']);
        }
        return $sort_nname;
    }
    return $sort_kl_name;
});
```

This looks a little messy, with lots of `if`s.  Let's simplify that with a `foreach`.

```
$sortLevels = array('kl_name', 'nname', 'vname');

usort($data, function($a, $b) use($sortLevels){
    foreach($sortLevels as $field){
        $sort = strnatcasecmp($a[$field], $a[$field]);
        if($sort !== 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return $sort;
});
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/173774